# SQLAlchemy: How to set alias for insert statement?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Need such a request:

```sql
    INSERT INTO public.cm_floor as r (load_date, centre, id_floor, name_floor)
        VALUES (now(), 'CentreName', 12345678, 'Floor 2')
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cm_floor_pkey
        DO UPDATE SET load_date=now(), centre=excluded.name_floor=excluded.name_floor
        WHERE (row_to_json(EXCLUDED)::jsonb - 'load_date') IS DISTINCT FROM (row_to_json(r.*)::jsonb - 'load_date');
```

Python code:

```python
table = metadata.tables["public.cm_floor"]

records = {
    ...
}

insert_stmt = insert(table).values(records)
do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=primary_keys, set_=update_column,
                                                   where=text("(row_to_json(EXCLUDED)::jsonb - 'load_date') IS DISTINCT FROM (row_to_json(r.*)::jsonb - 'load_date')')"))
```

I do not understand how to set the alias **r**. Or write the request differently. Without a alias.

Answer (score 1):

my solution to the problem:

```python
filter = [c != insert_stmt.excluded[c.name] for c in table.c if (not c.primary_key and c.name != "load_date")]

do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=primary_keys, set_=update_column, where=or_(*filter))
```

The final query looks like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.cm_floor (load_date, centre, id_floor, name_floor)
VALUES (now(), 'Centre', 12345678, 'Floor 2')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cm_floor_pkey
DO UPDATE SET load_date=now(), centre=excluded.name_floor=excluded.name_floor
WHERE public.cm_floor.centre<>excluded.centre OR public.cm_floor.name_floor<>excluded.name_floor;
```